# How to use environmental variables in Terraform?

Tags: environment-variables, terraform

I'm trying to use environmental variables in my Terraform templates.
Even after sourcing `.env` files and double checking by running `echo $env_variable`, it still won't work.
This only works if I manually specify the password in the variable file...

variable file:

```
variable "password" {}
```

.env file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PASS="passwordfoo"
```

Then i run the following commands

```
terraform init
terraform plan \
-var "password=$PASS" \
```

And when I try `terraform apply` it prompts me:

```
terraform apply
var.password
  Enter a value:
```

I expect it to run without problems.
I have followed the steps provided by HashiCorp themselves:
[reference links](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables).

Comment: The apply doesn't "remember" any options you passed to plan; you need to pass `terraform apply -var` also.

Comment: I see... but if I try the same with export `PUB="/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"`, It prompts me, and says: 
``` file: open $PUB: no such file or directory in: ``` Even tho it exists..

Comment: You can save yourself some hassle by exporting it as `TF_VAR_password` and just allowing Terraform to use that without having to specify vars separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

terraform doesn't get system environment variable as your way `export PASS="passwordfoo"`

change in `.env` as below code and source it, it should work directly, you don't need feed as `-var "password=$PASS"`

```
#!/bin/bash
export TF_VAR_password="passwordfoo"
```

Reference:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Terraform can read Environment variables using `tchupp` provider.

**Provider**: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/tchupp/env/latest/docs/data-sources/variable
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/tchupp/env/latest/docs/resources/variable

**Example**: https://github.com/tchupp/terraform-provider-env/blob/main/example/main.tf

```
provider "env" {}

resource "env_variable" "user" {
  name = "USER"
}

data "env_variable" "shell" {
  name = "SHELL"
}

terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.13"
  required_providers {
    env = {
      source  = "github.com/tchupp/env"
    }
  }
}
```